# trying to pull the number of likes from a facebook fanpage using JSONP and JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to pull and print just the number of "likes" a certain fanpage has, after doing some research - I found that this should work, but its not pulling anything. Any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fbFetch(){
    //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";

    //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        var html = "<ul>
                        <li>" + likes + "</li>
                    </ul>";

        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        });

        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body onload="fbFetch()">
    <div class="facebookfeed">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get a javascript error in the console.  Try to run the function on jquery document ready instead of body onLoad. Also, `likes` is not defined, it should be json.likes.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";

    //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        var html = "<ul><li>" + json.likes + "</li></ul>";
        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        });
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="facebookfeed">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working - that ?callback=? is because I'm pulling the JSON from a different domain (facebook)

Comment: I will do! Also do you think you can help me with something else? I changed the ul>li to div with an id - and that works perfect but at the end of this file I added this but its not working :-/ 

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var x   =document.getElementsByClassName("connect_widget_button_count_count")[0].innerHTML;

if (x < 153) {
document.write("worked")
}
else {
document.write("didn't work")
}
</script>

Comment: @Marco: You should rather [ask that as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), as it does not appear to be related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the url by it's ID instead?  Also the https / http same protocol applies here.  You may need to call the url with document.location.protocol, to match the current protocol of the calling document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fbFetch(){
    //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
    var url = document.location.protocol + "//graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";

    //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        var html = "<ul>
                        <li>" + likes + "</li>
                    </ul>";

        //A little animation once fetched
        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
            $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
        });

        $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body onload="fbFetch()">
    <div class="facebookfeed">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```