# using json to pull in facebook likes for multiple pages

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I have been looking around for a jQuery json method to pull in stats for a given facebook, for a project that I am starting in uni. I found this had already been asked here: [trying to pull the number of likes from a facebook fanpage using JSONP and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194086/trying-to-pull-the-number-of-likes-from-a-facebook-fanpage-using-jsonp-and-jquer)

Having used the code for my page, it works great, and is lightweight, however I am now wanting to use this code to pull in the results from multiple pages, but have tried to find a solution and hit a brick wall.

My current code, pulling in one page's data is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/immbudden?callback=?";

        //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            var html = "<ul><li>" + json.likes + "</li><li>" + json.about + "</li></ul>";
            //A little animation once fetched
            $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
                $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
            });
            $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
        });
      });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper"><!--wrapper open-->
        <div class="facebookfeed">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
    </div><!--wrapper closed-->
</body>
```

I am literally just starting to properly delve into jQuery, so any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can batch request the Facebook API so you don't even need to make multiple calls for multiple pages :)

The batch request looks something like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=id1,id2,id3` etc. You would then need to loop through the results to print them out. So the entire change would look like so:

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=immbudden,page2,page3&callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    var html = '';

    $.each(json, function(index, item) {
        html += "<ul><li>" + item.likes + "</li><li>" + item.about + "</li></ul>";
    });

    //A little animation once fetched
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
        $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
    });
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
});
```

I've created a working jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/rYyzf/

Comment: ahh I see, excellent :) thanks! one question though, In the way I am going to be using each callback, each id will be appearing in its own div, which will contain an illustration and other info for each facebook page. will this method allow this? thanks again :)

Comment: Of course, simply edit the loop to put each item in it's own div and format however you like :)

Comment: I have been trying today to append each item into the specified div, but can't seem to function correctly, here is a jsFiddle with the code i've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/immbudden/PRA7b/

I'm probably doing something stupid, but can't seem to work it out, still reading through my jQuery book and learning so apologies in advance haha.

Comment: What are the requirements? Do the divs have to exist before the json data is retrieved? If not, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PRA7b/1/

Comment: Yea the divs have to be present before the json data is received. The idea is that the section of the page will have an illustration, list of links and facebook data(which will be pulled from the json), the illustrations and links etc will be built into the site statically. The idea is that simply to change the information on the section, you can do it through facebook, rather than having to manually update it on the site.

Comment: In that case, just set up the initial divs with an ID that matches the page you are retrieving. Then in the loop check the index (which is the page id/vanity url) and populate the relevant div. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PRA7b/2/

Comment: Ah I see what you've done, and kinda understand, and it works :D thanks so so much, I've been racking my brains with this one! Il credit you the answer now :D

You the man, and thanks again. 
MB