# JSON - get facebook total count from url

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This script takes the number of likes from a facebook fan page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/tenniswarehouse?callback=?";

//Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    var html = "<ul><li>" + json.likes + "</li></ul>";
    //A little animation once fetched
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
        $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
    });
    $('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="facebookfeed">
<h2>Loading...</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194086/trying-to-pull-the-number-of-likes-from-a-facebook-fanpage-using-jsonp-and-jquer/24601527)

I tried to make him take the total number of likes,shares and comments from a url("[total_count](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27)") , but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=    %27http://www.google.com%27?callback=?";

//Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
var html = "<ul><li>" + json.total_count + "</li></ul>";
//A little animation once fetched
$('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
$('.facebookfeed').html(html);
});
$('.facebookfeed').animate({opacity:1}, 500);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="facebookfeed">
<h2>Loading...</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me make the script get the "[total_count](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27)" from links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess

```
var html = "<ul><li>" + json.data[0].total_count + "</li></ul>";
```

should do... Be sure to remove surplus spaces from the URL in the FQL as well.

Have a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e24ey/1/

Comment: It doesn't work.
I can't remove some spaces because it won't work after.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You have surplus spaces in your FQL: `WHERE%20url=    %27http://www.google.com`

Comment: This is the url 
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27

I removed the surplus of spaces, but it doesn't work.

Comment: *WHAT* exaclty doesn't work? You should be more specific, or otherwise nobody can help you...